# How do I find the length of two legs in a right triangle if I know the length of the hypotenuse and the interior angles

Tags: trigonometry

So if I know the angles of a right triangle and I knew the hypotenuse of the triangle, how would I find the length of the other two sides?

Comment: sin x=opp/hyp..

Comment: $sin(\alpha)$ = opposite side/hypotenuse

Answer (score 3):

> We've got this and we know $\angle\text{A}$ and $\angle\text{B}$ and $\angle\text{C}$ and $\text{c}$:
>
> [image]

---

Then we get, using the Pythagorean Theorem:

$$\text{a}^2+\text{b}^2=\text{c}^2$$

And use:

- $$\sin(\angle\text{A})=\frac{\text{a}}{\text{c}}\space\space\wedge\space\space\sin(\angle\text{B})=\frac{\text{b}}{\text{c}}$$
- $$\cos(\angle\text{A})=\frac{\text{b}}{\text{c}}\space\space\wedge\space\space\cos(\angle\text{B})=\frac{\text{a}}{\text{b}}$$
- $$\tan(\angle\text{A})=\frac{\text{a}}{\text{b}}\space\space\wedge\space\space\tan(\angle\text{B})=\frac{\text{b}}{\text{a}}$$

Answer (score 2):

By using trigonometry or by directly using sine law i.e $sina/A=sinb/B=sinc/C$ where a,b,c are the angles and $A,B,C$ sides opposite to angles.

Comment: thanks for the quick answer, it really helped.